# link_to :confirm displays popup twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This tag with rails 3

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', item, :method => :delete,:confirm=>'Are you sure?' %>
```

produces this html

```
<a href="/news/3" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

The entry is deleted, the problem is that the popup appears twice.

What could be causing this?

Comment: what JavaScript library are you using?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It sounds like the confirmation handler Javascript in rails.js is being attached twice.

Could you be accidentally including two copies of rails.js via duplication of a javascript_include_tag helper?

Comment: D'oh! That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Why I don't have a rails.js file?

Comment: @Tony If you are using Rails 3.1 or later, rails.js was replaced by jquery.js and jquery_ujs in the Asset Pipeline

Comment: For me on Rails 4, Turbolinks was rebinding jQuery event handlers multiple times.  Using jquery.turbolinks fixed the problem: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/blob/master/README.md

Comment: On Rails 5, `rails-ujs` does the job, so using it along with `jquery_ujs` would cause the same problem. Keep one or the other.

Comment: That worked for me - deleting `jquery_ujs`, which was replicated within `rails_ujs`, from `application.js` stopped the pop-up appearing twice. That was in Rails 5.

Comment: solution provided by @JoãoMarceloSouza worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 77):

I was having this same issue, and spent the better part of an hour looking into it. I found a solution in my situation, and I figured I would share it in case it helps...

My problem was that I had

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

in **config/environments/development.rb**

Changing that line to

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

fixed the confirmation duplication for me. I found the relevant information in [this rails guide to asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Hope it helps!

Comment: Same here. I found that I could leave debug on if I deleted compiled assets from development server.

Comment: Thanks--could not figure out why the heck this was happening.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that like any other environment config, this also required me to restart my rails server. (just in case someone gets tripped up by that as well).

Comment: Your the man with the answer! Don't know why I haven't encountered this until now, but it was driving me nuts! Thank you!

Comment: I think @tybro0103 comment to the answer has a better solution. There are so many ways to solve every problem in rails and a lot of the time it is just too easy to set some config to false but this isn't the right way. There is a reason this error is happening and turning off something that just gets rid of the problem isn't always a good solution. What if you really needed `config.assets.debug` set to true? I do think this is a bug in rails so maybe there is no right solution but deleting code that will be regenerated seems better than turning something off that may cause problems later.

Comment: @DutGRIFF I don't have compiled assets in my development environment and I was still getting this duplicated confirmation box.

Answer (score 45):

I've been used to include the `javascript_include_tag` at the bottom of my haml-layout-file.

With Rails4 and Turbolinks it happens that:

- Everything ok on the first load of a page (popup for confirmation appears only once)
- Visiting another page -> popup occurs twice
- Visiting one more page -> popup occurs three times
- and so on
- until I reload the page.

I solved the problem by moving the `javascript_include_tag` from the bottom into `<head>`

Comment: This is it! Turbolinks doesn't reload the whole page, it only reloads body, title (and some other things), but since my javascripts were in the body - those were being re-applied multiple times! Thank you, Nockenfell!

Comment: This not only worked for me, it fixed my Twitter Bootstrap pulldown menus -- they were appearing after a page reload, but not after following a link to another page.

Comment: This fixed my problem too! Thanks

Comment: @AlexKovshovik But Is it good to put Javascript in head section?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to put JS in header if you're using Turbolinks

Answer (score 5):

I copy this solution from another post, but this is what worked for me (rails 5)

"remove jquery_ujs from your application.js as rails_ujs is enough for later rails version."

I had included:
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require rails-ujs`

and after deleting it, all works fine.
Solution from: [Why am I getting a JQuery alert twice in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113810/why-am-i-getting-a-jquery-alert-twice-in-rails)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Rails 4 and none of the answers worked for me, however the following worked... I changed the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>.
```

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/244

Answer (score 2):

Great answers here,

But if you did everything and still get those double popups, and if you are running in **development mode**, check if you have `public/assets` loaded with compiled assets.

Deleting `public/assets/*` solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be a bug in Rails. Apparently directives in application.js are not only expanded into individual files when debug mode is enabled, but they are also included in application.js. I haven't looked at the Rails code for this but assume it is due to application.js being the default JavaScript file. If you rename this file to something else, lets say default.js it will in debug mode correctly include the files specified by the directive and default.js will only output JavaScript which is only in that file. Thus not generating duplicate code.

Example:

application.js

//= require jquery_ujs

foo();

Results in:

1) jquery_ujs.js

2) application.js with jquery_ujs contents and foo()

---

default.js

//= require jquery_ujs

foo();

Results in:

1) jquery_ujs.js

2) default.js with foo()

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with Rails 3.2.12, but simply updating to 3.2.13 solved that problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case jQuery was loaded twice because of the line
`//= require_tree .`

To prevent this error in application.js and application.css I'm used to create a subdirectory `app/assets/javascript/autorequire` and instead of `require_tree .` I do `require_tree ./autorequire`.

So, files in `app/assets/javascript` and `app/assets/stylesheets` are not included automatically/accidentally anymore. I put all my individual .css and .js files into the subdirectory and they are included implicitly. But I can define which files from the top-path are to be included and in which order.

Since I do so, I never had troubles by assets not loaded as I expect them to be.

Answer (score 1):

So for me it was because i had defined data-remote instead of just remote.

IE

data: { remote: true, ... }

instead of

remote: true, data: { ... }

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Rails 3.2.13), I had to **delete rails.js** to fix the same problem.

I did not explicitly reference rails.js, nor did changing config.assets.debug help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that the application had both "mootools ujs" and "jquery ujs" included. I got rid of the mootools one and now I only see one confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout haml like this have the twice pop up problem

```
%head
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
%body
  #calendar.calendarsize
```

Then I commend it and it works.

```
%head
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  -#= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
%body
  #calendar.calendarsize
```

Answer (score -1):

just remove the turbolinks, that worked for me in rails4

Comment: You can fix this problem with Turbolinks, you don't have to remove it.  For me on Rails 4, Turbolinks was rebinding jQuery event handlers multiple times.  Using jquery.turbolinks fixed the problem: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Using that logic, you could argue that removing jQuery would solve the problem as well. Turbolinks isn't the problem, it's the lack of knowledge about how to properly use turbolinks.

Answer (score -2):

Try to run either

```
rake assets:precompile ENV=development
```

or

```
rake assets:precompile ENV=production
```

Answer (score -4):

Delete:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. Despite of been commented it loads these js files. It works for me.

Comment: These lines are **not** "commented" as you suggested. Lines beginning with `//=` are actually [directives used to tell Sprockets the files that you wish to require](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives). Also, you likely do **not** want to delete the `//= require_tree .` line, as it tells *Sprockets* to recursively include all JavaScript files in the specified directory (in this case, `.`, the current directory). Finally, I think the reason this could have worked for you is because of removing the first two lines and having the `jquery-rails` gem.

Comment: As user664833 stated, this is NOT a comment inside the file.  This file is a manifest file that tells the assets pipeline which files to load.  If you read the comments in the default-generated file it tells you how it's used.  If you don't want to use sprockets/assets pipeline then go ahead and remove them. I personally recommend using them, though, as I've found it to make my coding more efficient.

Comment: You can't just remove Sprockets declarations. These are not commented lines ... they are instructions for loading the proper assets according to the asset pipeline.