# :confirm is generating two confirm messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the following code:

```
<li class="dele-yaniv"><%= link_to "delete", order, :method => :delete,
                                     :confirm => "You sure you want to delete " +order.name+"?",
                                     :title => order.name %></li>
```

when the uses click the delete link he gets a confirmation message "You sure you want to delete ?"

After clicking ok, another message appears again with a second line" check-box Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs

What going on?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475449/link-to-confirm-displays-popup-twice

Answer (score 0):

You should just interpolate the variable. I think the issue is a result of how you're passing the options for `:confirm`. You can include the variable inside the quotation marks by enclosing it in `#{` and `}` like this:

```
<li class="dele-yaniv">
  <%= link_to "delete", order, :method => :delete,
                               :confirm => "You sure you want to delete #{order.name}?",
                               :title => order.name %>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this did not do the trick. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think it has to due with the confirmation handler Javascript being attached twice. Check the way your `<%= javascript_include_tag %>` is adding Javascript to make sure nothing is being duplicated.

Comment: should i look for duplicate usage of the javascript_include_tag?

Answer (score 0):

Is it rails 3.1 with asset pipeline?

I don't know if this is what's happening to you, but recently I ran into a problem where the asset pipeline was caching my js in a corrupt way, causing certain JS to be executed twice.

```
rm -rf ./public/cache
rm -rf ./tmp/assets
```

to delete all sprockets/asset pipeline caches, and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was including jquery and twitter bootstrap in my javascript manifest.
It appears that bootstrap also includes jquery functionality.

My old gemfile with 2 confirm dialogues:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

My new gemfile:

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```