# jQuery-turbolinks - link_to confirm: pops up several times times in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a typical CRUD operation application with

apps/views/recipe/show.html.haml
containing a line

```
= link_to "Delete", recipe_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default"
```

If I create a new recipe in apps/views/recipe/new.html.haml and get redirected to 
apps/views/recipe/show.html.haml and hit Delete, then it gives me confirmation once and deletes the recipe.

However, if I go to the same show page from typical type of index.html.haml that links to individual recipe such as http://localhost:3000/recipes/29 and hit Delete button, the confirmation will pop up 3-4 times.. (UNLESS I REFRESH that page first, then it will pop up confirm only once).

I tried adding jQuery-turbolinks and it still didn't work...

app/views/layouts/application.html.haml has the following under %title

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                      
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                                    
  = csrf_meta_tags
```

Not sure how to fix it so it doesn't pop up several times

**EDIT:** Still same behaviour even after I fix the code by passing the @recipe

```
= link_to "Delete", recipe_path(@recipe), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default"
```

**EDIT 2:**
If I remove turbolinks all together it works buttTurbolinks makes following links in your web application faster and as I understand are used in most Rails projects. So trying to see if there is a work around? Seems like a pretty typical thing to be able to do.

**EDIT 3:**

I added jQuery-turbolinks

Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

The confirmation pops more than once still. There must be a way to fix it?

**EDIT 4:**
I found the problem. The %head in HTML was right under %html and wasn't indented properly so application.js and others were included in the body and not the head section so instead of

```
!!! 5                                                                                                                                                                                                             
%html                                                                                                                                                                                                             
%head                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    %title Recipe App                                                                                                                                                                                             
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                                                                         
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                                                                                       
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

It should have been

```
!!! 5                                                                                                                                                                                                             
%html                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  %head                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    %title Recipe App                                                                                                                                                                                             
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                                                                         
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true                                                                                                                                       
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

Comment: Do you have any custom javascript / coffeescript loaded?

Comment: @fylooi No all standard barebone app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*jquery-turbolinks* should not really be necessary; my apps work correctly without it...

Are you sure that:

- you have the `javascript_include_tag ...` line in the `<head>` part of your html?
- you have only one `javascript_include_tag ...` line?

---

**background**:

The problem you have is that the *jquery_ujs* setup is called on every *turbolinks* page load resulting in duplicated handlers being installed.
Since a *turbolinks* page load just replaces the `<body>` part of the document you must be doing something inside your `<body>` that triggers *jquery_ujs* setup...

See also these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18260585/211060 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475479/211060

Comment: Yes you were right.. javascript_include_tag was not in head.. the indent of the code was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're including multiple copies of rails.js?

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475479/862479) post and see if solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing the `id` of the `recipe` being deleted as a parameter to the `recipe_path`, probably as follows:

```
= link_to "Delete", recipe_path(recipe), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default"
```

Without an object being passed, I am guessing it is deleting many records.

Comment: Good catch of me not passing the recipe object but for some reason that didn't fix it. Remember if I refresh the show page, the confirm box pops up only once.. so it has to do something with turbolinks I am guessing?

Answer (score 2):

i faced this similar issue and resolved after identifying the errors:-

1. i had the `layout` with `application.js` included
2. my `partial` was again including `jquery.min` which was already included in `application.js` `already included`
3. i was using `getScript()` **multiple times** in few js files..which should be only once per event.

Hope this helps.