# Check for :confirmation on password cause 2 prompts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a signup form that asks for `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation`. The following validations are present in my `User` model

```
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/
  validates :password, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil:
```

This causes 2 prompts when the `password` and `password_confirmation` do not match.

[image]

I found [link_to :confirm displays popup twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475449/link-to-confirm-displays-popup-twice) but it refers to Rails 3 and none of the solutions work on Rails 4. How to I ensure only 1 prompt?

2 prompts are displayed **only during password mismatch** and not when email is invalid or password is too short.

Comment: The answers you linked seem to really cover everything that might have gone wrong here. Are you sure you tried all the suggestions? Mainly those about javascript duplication. Have you tried e.g. disabling turbolinks?

Comment: @PiotrKruczek Yes I tried everything on that link and nothing has worked so far. There were no `rails.js` or any such file that would cause javascript duplication. Disabling turbo links did not do the job.