# Rails 4.2.3 - Destroy :confirm comes up multiple times for some reason

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Before I decided to make this post, I looked at an older question that was asked about this exact topic: [link_to :confirm displays popup twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475449/link-to-confirm-displays-popup-twice)

However, the quest was asked a few years ago and I am not entirely sure I understand what the top answer is suggesting.

I have the following:

```
= link_to "Delete", userpost_path, method: :delete, 
  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
  class: "btn btn-default"
```

What happens is that when the user clicks on OK in the popup, the record is deleted from the database.  However, the message comes up like 2-3 times.

Here's what I have in the head of my application.html.haml layout file:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
= csrf_meta_tags
```

In my application.js, this is all I have:

```
//= require jquery    
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I am not sure what "**It sounds like the confirmation handler Javascript in rails.js is being attached twice**" means.  I realize I am probably asking a very simple, newbie question, but after attempting some of the other things listed by other users, I am still receiving the multiple popups.  Also, I cannot do something like `= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false` because I need javascript for masonry.

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: is this is happening in production environment?

Comment: Hi Naveed.  No, it is just for a simple project running on localhost as I teach myself rails.

Comment: Gotcha, try your app in production env. Also `javascript_include_tag` should  be in <head> tag. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks Naveed.  Again, sorry about this but I'm going to need some help.  In the head I already have = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true

Comment: simply run your application in production mode, `rails s -e production` ( you need to fix your database configuration for production first). Test again if you didn't see this issue in production all is well, development env has lot of glitches( assets complication etc and especially if you are using turbolinks )

Comment: have you tried simply `confirm` instead of `data confirm`? (i.e. `= link_to "Delete", userpost_path, method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?", 
  class: "btn btn-default" `)

Comment: Thanks Naveed.  I will try this tomorrow when I have access to PC again.  Thank you Vasseurth I will check tomorrow.

Comment: hello unfortunately it is closed and I cannot go on the PC today.  thanks again I will have to work on this next week.