# Why am I getting a JQuery alert twice in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jquery confirmation on a delete link. The confirmation pops up just fine when you click on the link, however, it pops up a second time when you click 'OK'. I can not figure out why. Other than having to click 'OK' twice, the method works fine and the post gets deleted.

---

```
show.html.haml

%h1= @post.title
%p= @post.description

%p= link_to 'Back', root_path
%p= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path
%p= link_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this Post?' }
```

---

```
posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
.
.
.
  def destroy
      @post.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post successfully deleted.'
  end
.
.
.
  def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

---

```
Gemfile

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'haml', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.4'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

---

```
application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: that might be in your jquery code? check it or post it here for help

Comment: The jquery code is the standard jquery that the gem inserts into the pipeline. I've not altered the source jquery in any way. I will check the jquery gems github for any bug reports on this, though. Thanks.

Comment: @olucube, where you the one that made the comment then deleted it asking if both jquery_ujs and rails-ujs were needed?

Comment: didn't get your question please

Comment: someone posted a comment that asked if I needed both the jquery_ujs and the rails-ujs in the application.js file. They deleted the comment before I could respond. I was asking if you were the one who posted the comment.

Comment: no; you might remove jquery_ujs if you're use recent rails

Comment: Yes, that was what I found out after much reading. rails-ujs duplicates all of the functionality of jquery_ujs, making it redundant. Removing jquery_ujs fixed it. If you make this solution an official answer, I will mark it as accepted. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove jquery_ujs from your application.js as rails_ujs is enough for later rails version.